# I mistakenly deleted php-fpm 7.0 pool.d/www.conf, how could I restore it?

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm

I mistakenly deleted php-fpm 7.0 `pool.d/www.conf`, how could I restore it?

I tried:

```
apt-get upgrade php-fpm
```

Without update before that. It seems I'm still in the range of 7.0.

But I think the file remained the same.

How could I restore it after having deleted data inside it?

I should make a backup next time before editing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a version that suited for me here:

https://gist.github.com/mustafaturan/3942448